# how to make background image to be one full page without cropping the image

Tags: html, css, image, size

I am trying to make the webpage, and I have trouble setting the background image of the webpage. I want my background image to be one full page without cropping or zooming the image or requiring scrolling.
I have my background image with the size of 1920x1080. I thought this size should make the webpage to be one full page, but it did not. What should I do for the image to fit on one page?

```
   background-image: url('image/background1-1.png');
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
```

This code is what I have done for the background image, but it crops the image.

Also, I am following the size or location of the images from the design that I did in XD. However, it does not match if I apply it as a code. For example, according to XD, the location of the text is top: 328px; left: 786px, but if I apply this information to my code, the text does not appear where the text is supposed to appear.

I am struggling with these questions.
I would appreciate your help as I do not have much knowledge regarding this topic.

Comment: You cannot have this for all devices as their aspect ratios differ. The best you can do is background size cover which will crop top and bottom or the sides as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `background-size` property. If you truly don't want to crop the image at all, use `contain`, but this will likely not feel like a true background image. `cover` will enlarge the image just enough to fit within the bounds of the browser window's dimensions, and will crop it slightly when the browser's w/h ratio isn't identical to your images w/h ratio.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

```
background-image: url('image/background1-1.png');
background-color: #000;
background-position:center center;
background-repeat; no-repeat;
background-size: cover; /* contain */
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add this

```
    background-image: "url(/meals/3.jpg)",
    background-position: "center",
    background-repeat: "no-repeat",
    background-size: "cover",
```